# Error creating bean with name 'routerFunctionMapping' - CGLIB subclass generation issue in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-boot-devtools

I'm encountering an issue while trying to run my Spring Cloud Gateway application. The application fails to start, and I'm getting a BeanCreationException with a java.lang.IllegalAccessError related to CGLIB subclass generation. The error seems to be occurring in the context of Spring Boot devtools.

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'routerFunctionMapping'...
...
Caused by: org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError...
...
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.shubham</groupId>
    <artifactId>Posts</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Posts</name>
    <description>Spring cloud gateway Project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.9</version>
</dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-asm</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-docker-compose</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-testcontainers</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                    <compilerArgs>--enable-preview</compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Root Cause:
`org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError` 
Class Involved:
`class org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.config.GatewayMvcPropertiesBeanDefinitionRegistrar$RouterFunctionHolder`

Error Message:
`class org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.config.GatewayMvcPropertiesBeanDefinitionRegistrar$RouterFunctionHolder$$SpringCGLIB$$1 cannot access its superclass org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.config.GatewayMvcPropertiesBeanDefinitionRegistrar$RouterFunctionHolder`

Details:

The problematic class is `org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.config.GatewayMvcPropertiesBeanDefinitionRegistrar$RouterFunctionHolder.`
The error suggests an issue with access to the superclass during CGLIB subclass generation.

Possible Causes:

The class might be marked as final or non-visible.
There could be conflicts with Spring Boot devtools or other dependencies.
Steps Taken:

Checked the visibility and finality of the class.
Reviewed project dependencies and configurations.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with CGLIB subclass generation in Spring Cloud Gateway? What steps can I take to resolve this problem?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Removing devtools fixes the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue might have been caused by a conflict or compatibility problem between the Spring Cloud version you were using and other dependencies or the Spring Boot devtools. By removing the Spring Cloud dependency, you eliminated the source of the problem.

By removing Spring Cloud Dependency , it works

Answer (score 0):

This issue was identified and fixed on the official Spring repo. It's part of 4.1.2 Milestone.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/3199